# Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table - In clone project

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, phpunit

everybody!

I've finished a laravel project backend with postgres and it has a phpunit tests, everything it works. 
So, I did upload to Github. 
When I did "git clone" on this project to test and I try run phpunit (vendor/bin/phpunit) For my surprise, I got so many errors. Here's some errors:

---

1) Tests\Feature\ApiTransacaoTest::testApiSaldo with data set #0 ('2769')
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: contas (SQL: select * from "contas" where "conta" = 2769 limit 1)
....
...
Caused by
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: contas

---

Well, I have now 2 projects technically equals, but the original runs phpunit and coverage tests, but clone doesn't.

*** In this clone project, I can test endpoints with Insomnia, that's ok, but when I try test anything with phpunit I catch errors above ***

I'm trying discover the solution about whole day.

Please, someone can help me?

(phpunit.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.xsd"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="Feature">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <php>
        <server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <server name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
        <server name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
        <server name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
        <server name="MAIL_MAILER" value="array"/>
        <server name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
        <server name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <server name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

(.env)

```
 APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:tztSHn9WsiV3WUBmjx+NbQbGakMi2TNxxxrKa9NEkZU=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=banco
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=docker

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Comment: When you run phpunit what is your database settings for that, most likely located in phpunit.xml

Comment: I've edited post and put it there. The phpunit.xml is exactly same of original project, after all I did a git clone.

Comment: I forgot mentionated that postgres is a docker container. I'm not sure it can be a problem.

Comment: This seems like you don't run your migrations in your tests, can you include the TestCase construct() from the tests folder

Comment: I renamed all .gitignore from my project, then I did git push. 
The result is that all project was sent to github (including vendor, node_modules..), everything!
So I run git clone again. And guess?
All tests has been passed. 
I suspect that some important files needs to go github, but I don't know wich ones.

Comment: you ignored my comment, you run a memory database on tests. If that does not have the table, the migration has not ranned, either it is not setup correctly in the test case or you dont have the migration anymore

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
use RefreshDatabase;
```

into your test cases.

Comment: answer is a comment